# Set a Single Select control as required in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a filter control with style "Single Select". This filter has two options: "New Users" and "All Users", by default its value is "All Users".

Now I need to force one of the options is always selected. Is there a way to achieve this? It's something like set this control as "required".

Answer (score 5):

Added a GIF to elaborate on the below.

1. ***Default Selection***: Are you looking to have a default value? that could be achieved by adding the required value into the "*Default Selection*" section in the Data Tab of the Filter Control.

> "*I need to force one of the options is always selected*"

2. ***Fixed Value***: If you are looking to always include a certain value, then the regular Multi select [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) would be required.  One way to ensure that viewers can't deselect a value from a Filter Control is to use a *Fixed Size* Filter Control (sorted by Dimension in the required order) and add a transparent shape over the respective area checkbox area of the Filter Control (as well as the deselect all checkbox at the top of the Filter Control.

[image]